# dijit.byId return undefined

Tags: dojo, undefined

It's very strange, I call dijit.byId() in dojo.addOnLoad(function{...}), it return undefined. In order to check if the id exist, i call dojo.byId() at the same time, it return some object. So I guess the component is not a dijit component? this is the whole code: Please help me, thanks in advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>

<!-- Dojo/Diji definations -->
<link href='../dojoroot/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='../dojoroot/dojo/resources/dojo.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>


<!-- Main scripts -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function()
    {
        // Include library
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");

        // add the select child event to the tab panel
        alert(dijit.byId("contentTabPanel"));  // return no defined
        alert(dojo.byId("contentTabPanel")); // return an object

    });
</script>
</head>

<body class="tundra">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <!-- Content Tab Panel -->
    <div id="contentTabPanel" dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center">
        <!-- Tab UserGroup -->
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="UserGroup">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

OMFG!!!!! I know the reason!!!!! I cost 5 Hours just for this STUPID error:

I MUST write the

```
    // Include library
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
```

outside the dojo.addOnLoad(function() { !!!

Comment: Surely your browser's developer tools should be giving you lots of errors before that?  Something like you haven't required-in your dijit modules...

Comment: I know it's long after the question has been asked, but if you solved your question, it's a good practice to self-answer, so that the question no longer haunts in the "unanswered" tab.